# How do I browse all Razor views with their paths?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

In `ASP.NET Core 2.2` you can have the view anywhere you want, in any folder and it will be used if there's a valid path specified.

E.g. You can specify the path as a parameter of a `View` function returned from the `Controller` `Action` like this.

```
return View("Path/To/View", model);
```

Or you write your own implementation of `IViewLocationExpander`.

This got me wondering.

When you build `ASP.NET Core 2.2` application, the folders in which views reside disappear from the build files together with the views themselves because they are compiled into the source code.

Yet for discovering the views the paths are still needed. This means that `Razor` somehow knows where the view was in the solution and that information must be in the source somewhere.

Can you still list all the `.cshtml` views with their full paths in the compiled code? Or browse all the view folders recursively?

Comment: You can get a view and render it (IRazorViewEngine), so you should be able to get all views if you have a list with all paths.